# Removing Background From PDF Files using itextsharp in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I have downloaded some pdf books from archive.org. These books are very heavy and needs a lot of system resources. However, if we remove the yellow background of pdf pages it runs smoother. Is there anyway I can remove all the yellow backgrounds skipping some pages which have certain images using itextsharp.

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do that with iTextSharp.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Also, to give you an idea, PDFs don't actually have anything called a "background image" and instead they just have images that might, from your perspective, be in the background. Minor difference but while trying to do this you'll want to keep that in mind. Also, it possible that the yellow thing isn't actually an image in the first place and instead a collection of vector drawing commands. But knowing these two you should be able to find several posts here about those subjects.